# Creating a loop to create NDVI images from raster stacks and naming them from the file name

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have been trying to write a loop to go through two folders of Sentinel 2 satellite images (Band 4 and 5) and get a NDVI for each date.

A stack is created for each band, some cropping and resampling to finally proceed to the NDVI calculation. I struggle with the integration of the NDVI calculation in the loop and the file name creation.

I'd simply want my loop to generate x files for x dates and then give each NDVI images the date as a name "YYYY/MM/DD.tif" extracted from the file name. But I can't think of a way to do so, after a lot of unsuccessful trial and error.

```
#list files
files4 <- list.files(path4, pattern = "jp2$", full.names = TRUE)
files5 <- list.files(path5, pattern = "jp2$", full.names = TRUE)

ms5 <- stack()
ms4 <- stack()

for (f in files4){
  # loading a raster
  r4 <- raster(f)
  proj4string(r4)
  proj4string(emprise)
  emprise <- spTransform(emprise, proj4string(r4)) 
  r4b <- crop(r4, emprise)
  ms4<- stack(ms4,r4b)
#copy the date from the file to give a name to the final NDVI image (I have to get ride of everything but the date
  x <- gsub("[A-z //.//(//)]", "", r4)
  y <- substr(x, 4, 11)
}


for (f in files5){
  # load the raster
  r5 <- raster(f)
  proj4string(r5)
  proj4string(emprise)
  emprise <- spTransform(emprise, proj4string(r5)) 
  r5b <- crop(r5, emprise)
  ms5<- stack(ms5,r5b)
}

#Resampling : setting the Band 5 to the same resolution as Band 4 
b5_resamp <- resample(ms5, ms4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered looping over dates rather than files? I can't give more specific advice without example data, but here is the general idea:

```
# List files
files4 <- list.files("./band4", pattern = ".tif", full.names = TRUE)
#> "band4/T31UDR_20170126T105321_B04.tif" "band4/T31UDR_20180126T105321_B04.tif"

files5 <- list.files("./band5", pattern = ".tif", full.names = TRUE)
#> "./band5/T31UDR_20170126T105321_B05.tif" "./band5/T31UDR_20180126T105321_B05.tif"

# Get dates
dates <- unique(gsub(pattern = ".*_(\\d{8}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = c(files4, files5)))
#> "20170126" "20180126"

# Define empty stacks
ms5 <- stack()
ms4 <- stack()

for(date in dates){
  
  ## Band 4
  
  f4 <- list.files("./band4", pattern = date, full.names = TRUE)
  
  # loading a raster
  r4 <- raster(f4)
  proj4string(r4)
  proj4string(emprise)
  emprise <- spTransform(emprise, proj4string(r4)) 
  r4b <- crop(r4, emprise)
  ms4 <- stack(ms4,r4b)
  
  ## Band 5
  
  f5 <- list.files("./band5", pattern = date, full.names = TRUE)
  
  # load the raster
  r5 <- raster(f5)
  proj4string(r5)
  proj4string(emprise)
  emprise <- spTransform(emprise, proj4string(r5)) 
  r5b <- crop(r5, emprise)
  ms5<- stack(ms5,r5b)
  
  ## Resampling : setting the Band 5 to the same resolution as Band 4 
  
  b5_resamp <- resample(ms5, ms4)

  ## Write to file
  
  writeRaster(b5_resamp, filename = paste0(date, ".tif"))
}
```

Comment: That could work if those dates match the dates on the raw files. In other words, are any files returned when you run `list.files(path4, pattern = date, full.names = TRUE)` with one of those dates?

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I got the gist of the code you've written. I've tried it but there is a little issue. the value returned by `dates <- unique(gsub(pattern = "[A-z //.//(//)]", replacement = "",x = c(files4, files5)))` is a long string with number that does not find a match when iterating because the files names go like this :T31UDR_20170126T105321_B04.jp2 and in your code you take only the numbers. I don't think I can tweak that line to make it work. It's the thing preventing the code from working..

Comment: So, no date is returned because `date` does not find a match in the directory

Comment: Do you know all the dates already, if so, it might be fastest to just hard code dates, like `dates <- c(20170126, 20170226, ...)`. Or you could get the dates dynamically from `list.files()` if there is a consistent pattern in raw imagery file names, like `gsub(pattern = ".*_(\\d{8}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "T31UDR_20170126T105321_B04.jp2")` where `x` is similar to `files4` and `files5`.

Comment: Then (assuming one image per date per band), match on a single image per iteration of the loop `f4 <- list.files(path4, pattern = date, full.names = TRUE)`. If you share the results of `fs::dir_tree(path = path4, recurse = TRUE)` in your question, I can provide specific advice to match your situation.

Comment: it's a consistent pattern so I am able to store them all in "date" under this format (YYYYMMDD) which is enough for me. Everything seems to work fine

the beginning is now
 `dates <- unique(gsub(pattern = "[A-z //.//(//)]", replacement = "",x = c(files4, files5)))
dates  <- substr(files4, 54, 75)`
this gives me a key to retrieve the band 4 and 5. 
But I dont know how to in the end save the NDVI image i've got. 
all I have is : 
`ndvi <- ((b5_resamp-ms4)-(b5_resamp+ms4))
  writeRaster(ndvi, filename = paste0(date, ".tif",overwrite=TRUE))`

Comment: Glad you are making progress. All that looks ok except a typo: try `writeRaster(ndvi, filename = paste0(date, ".tif"),overwrite=TRUE)`

Comment: Yes, the typo was making the loop crash. Do you know where the raster created with `writeRaster()` ? I can't find any info from the R resource to locate the files created or how to tweak this line to save the files in a directory I choose. thanks again

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work ! thanks for everything.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck